# Can soulmelds of one class be bound to a chakra opened by another class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, multi-classing, meldshaping

I'm playing a totemist. I want to deal more damage and expand my versatility by multiclassing into incarnate, but I've a question.

Does having the ability to bind a soulmeld to a chakra that's opened by having levels in the totemist class allow a creature to bind to that chakra a soulmeld gained from, for example, the incarnate class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can bind Incarnate melds to chakras unlocked via the Totemist class. The ability to bind a soulmeld to a given chakra is an ability that, once obtained, is independent of the phenomenon that granted it.

As far as I know, this is more a result of omission than something that is explicitly written out, however. The general rules for chakra binds (Magic of Incarnum page 51) do not mention that class-specific soulmelds can only be bound to a chakra unlocked via that class, and neither do the "Chakra Binds" class features themselves.
For a final argument, I will add that such a restriction would make the prestige classes, the spells, the feats, the power, and the magic item that grant additional chakra binds rather useless.